# Date Field Validation failed for type xsd:gYear type in SOAP ui

Tags: xml, soap, xsd, wsdl, soapui

I am having trouble to identify the validation logic that `SoapUI` implements.

There is one date field which is type `xsd:gYear` defined in my local XSD used in WSDL. When I am validating the value "20161411" its failed in SoapUI, but same field is by passing in java framework, which I have same XSD and same wsdl .

Field Is :

```
 <date>20171210</date>
```

It's type is xsd:gYear as defined in my XSD as below :-

```
 <xsd:simpleType name="Date_NoID">
     <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:gYear"/>
 </xsd:simpleType>
```

When I am providing the value as 20171210 which is 8 digit, it's throwing me the error in SOAPUI , which i am doing by right click --> validate .

The error message is

> "union value '20171210' does not match any members of 'Date in namespace http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1/xml/'".

If we give the value as "201615" which is six digit it's passes the validation in SOAPUI .

So I want to understand how SOAPUI, setting the maxlength for the Feild i.e of type xsd:gYear

The same field  is passing in JAVA, having same XSD reference using Schema Validator.

Comment: Can you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457050/can-xml-schema-be-written-to-allow-xsattribute-of-either-xsdate-or-xsdatetime) thread to see if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you defined you date field as a xsd:year only. which allows for a signed value of 4 or more agreed upon digits to represent a year (the extra allows to represent years far in the future or past).

Not sure why the six digits are passing since you probably did not set a 2 digit extension, but you should use xsd:date instead that should parse the date as you have it represented.

similar question:
[XSD validates wrong format of xs:date and xs:dateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691158/xsd-validates-wrong-format-of-xsdate-and-xsdatetime)

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the answer. I tried changing the definition as  <xsd:simpleType name="Date_NoID">
     <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:date"/>
 </xsd:simpleType>    in my XSD. Then also the SOAPUI accepts the "year" part of date to be 6 digit. i.e. SOAPUI doesn't validates <date>20171210-10-14</date> but validates <date>201712-10-14</date> and JAVA still validates the year as earlier

Comment: what is this date "20171210-10-14" supposed to be? that is not valid ISO date. Is 10 14 a time in hours and minutes? then you need to use datetime and have a T to delimit the date from the time part.

Comment: "20171210-10-14" is just a wrong date or say unrealistic date that JAVA validates if xsd:date is used in the referenced schema definition. SOAPUI doesn't validates it but it validates "201712-10-14" which is again an unrealistic date. 10 here is month and 14 is the day of month.

Comment: Good point not sure why xsd or java are allowing those as valid.

Comment: this is an excerpt from the ISO standard that may explain D.3.3 More Than 9999 Years

 To accommodate year values greater than 9999, more than four digits are allowed in the year representations of dateTime, date, gYearMonth, and gYear. This follows [ISO 8601:2000 Second Edition]. link:http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#deviantformats